# Why are VB.NET and C++ giving different results for same expression?

Tags: c++, vb.net, operators

Consider the following snippets:

**C++:**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   int x = 10, y = 20;
   y = x + (x=y)*0;
   cout << y;
   return 0;
}
```

which gives a result of `20`, because the value of `y` is assigned to `x` since the bracket is executed first according to the [Operator Precedence Table](http://www.difranco.net/compsci/C_Operator_Precedence_Table.htm).

**VB.NET:**

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
   Dim x As Integer = 10
   Dim y As Integer = 20
   y = x + (x = y) * 0
   MsgBox(y)
End Sub
```

which instead gives a result of `10`.

- What is the reason for this difference?
- What is the order of execution of operators in VB.NET?

Comment: `y = x + (x=y)*0;` What is with this line today, you're like the 3rd person.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unlike in C++, VB.NET's `=` is not always an assignment. It can also be the equality comparison operator (`==` in C++) if it appears inside an expression. Therefore your two expressions are not the same. They are not even equivalent. The VB.NET code does not do what you might think it does.

First to your C++ code: <strike>Like you're saying, the assignment `x=y` happens first; thus your code is roughly equivalent to this:</strike> (It seems that was incorrect; see [Jens' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25030909/240733).) Since you end up with `y` being `20`, it is likely that your C++ compiler evaluated your code as if you had written this:

```cpp
int x = 10, y = 20;
x = y;
y = x + x*0; // which is equivalent to `y = 20 + 20*0;`, or `y = 20 + 0;`, or `y = 20;`
```

In VB.NET however, because the `=` in your subexpression `(x=y)` is not actually interpreted as an assignment, but as a comparison, the code is equivalent to this:

```vb
Dim x As Integer = 10
Dim y As Integer = 20
y = 10 + False*0 ' which is equivalent to `y = 10 + 0*0`, or `y = 10` '
```

Here, operator precedence doesn't even come into play, but an implicit type conversion of the boolean value `False` to numeric `0`.

(Just in case you were wondering: In VB.NET, assignment inside an expression is impossible. Assignments must always be full statements of their own, they cannot happen "inline". Otherwise it would be impossible to tell whether a `=` inside an expression meant assignment or comparison, since the same operator is used for both.)

Comment: @ stakx : see the link in my answer the operator precedence is different for vb.net

Comment: @SujithKarivelil: Operator precedence in VB.NET simply doesn't matter here. See my answer.

Comment: The original post is undefined behavior, so the outcome is undefined independent on any operator precedence rule.

Answer (score 4):

Your C++ snippet is undefined behavior. There is no sequence point between using x as the first argument and assigning y to x, so the compiler can evaluate the sub-expressions in any order. Both

1. First evaluate the left side: y = 10 + (x=y) * 0 -> y = 10 + (x=20) * 0 -> y = 10 + 20*0
2. First evaluate the right side: y = x + (x=20) * 0 -> y = 20 + 20 * 0

It is also generally a very bad style to put assignments inside expressions.

Comment: C++11 has replaced sequence points with the concepts of sequenced, indeterminately sequenced, and unsequenced expressions, the general idea's the same though.

Comment: The compiler can evaluate the sub-expressions in any order anyway. The undefined behaviour just makes everything else undefined too.

Answer (score 4):

This answer was intended as a comment, but its length quickly exceeded the limit. Sorry :)

You are confusing **operator precedence** with **evaluation order**. (This is a very common phenomenon, so don't feel bad). Let me try to explain with a simpler example involving more familiar operators:

If you have an expression like `a + b * c` then yes, the multiplication will always happen before the addition, because the `*` *operator* binds tighter than `+` *operator*. So far so good? The important point is that C++ is allowed to evaluate the *operands* `a`, `b` and `c` in any order it pleases. If one of those operands has a side effect which affects another operand, this is bad for two reasons:

1. It may cause undefined behavior (which in your code is indeed the case), and more importantly
2. It is guaranteed to give future readers of your code serious headaches. **So please don't do it!**

By the way, Java will always evaluate `a` first, then `b`, then `c`, "despite" the fact that  multiplication happens before addition. The pseudo-bytecode will look like `push a; push b; push c; mul; add;`

(You did not ask about Java, but I wanted to mention Java to give an example where evaluating `a` is not only feasible, but *guaranteed* by the language specification. C# behaves the same way here.)

Comment: +1 but I feel that some important points are missing because you are focussing on the simple expressions `a`, `b`, and `c`. Let's include the composite expressions `a+…`, `b*c`, and `a+b*c`. We can then show that: **1.** In the expression `a+…`, we only have one operator; therefore, operator precedence does not matter here. Generally, operator precedence only matters in expressions with more than one operator. **2.** We can still say that `a` must be evaluated before `a+…` can be evaluated. Thus evaluation order is something that exists even where operator precedence does not.

Comment: **3.** Operator precedence *does* matter in `a+b*c`, where it influences evaluation order: `b*c` before `a+…`. So generally, operator precedence can *influence* evaluation order… **4.** … but as we've seen in (1), it is not necessarily the only influencing factor; that's one reason why the two concepts cannot be one and the same.